# Segfault after returning a pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code in C, trying to develop an Operating System simulation:

Queue.c:

```
typedef enum {running,readyproc,waiting,suspended}status;

typedef struct pcb {
   long pid;
   char* pname;
   long priority;
   long sleepperiod;
   long* context;
   status stat;


}PCB;

typedef enum {ready, timer, suspend} queuetype;
typedef struct {
   int size;
   int capacity;
   PCB ** data;
   queuetype qt;
}Queue;

void queue_init(Queue *q, queuetype qt){
   q->size =0;
   q->capacity = QUEUE_INITIAL_CAPACITY ;//100
   q->data = (PCB **)calloc(q->capacity,sizeof(PCB*));
   q->qt = qt;
}

PCB* queue_pop (Queue* q){
   PCB* toReturn;
   int i;
   toReturn = q->data[0];
   for (i=0;i<q->size;i++){
      q->data[i]=q->data [i+1];
   }
  free(q->data[q->size]);
  q->size--;
  printf ("toReturn id:%ld pname: %s\n", toReturn->pid, toReturn->pname);
  return toReturn;
}
```

Knowing that the queue gets initialized and filled with PCBs. I do always get a segafault on calling:

```
PCB* pcb = queue_pop(&queue);
```

EDIT:
Here is the function that would fill the queue:

```
void queue_append(Queue *q, PCB* value)
{
   q->data[q->size++] = value;
}
```

EDIT2:
the printf before the return in `queue_pop` returns this:

```
toReturn id: 2 pname: test1c_a
```

which corresponds to what I want to pop from that queue.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If that's too much effort then at least show how the queue is being initialized and filled.

Comment: the function `queue_init` normally initialises the queue.

Comment: `queue_init` makes the queue empty, and your `pop` function breaks if called on an empty queue

Comment: Perhaps you're freeing the values in the queue by mistake, or any other number of problems. We can't help you if you don't post a MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (i=0;i<q->size;i++){
      q->data[i]=q->data [i+1];
   }
```

If `q->size == q->capacity`, then you'll run off the end of `q->data` (it will access `q->data[q->capacity]`, which is one past its allocation length).

P.S. There are much more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: The loop (after fixing the length bug) is a good way to move several elements. It expresses the intent clearly and correctly; and a modern compiler will optimize it the same as if a `memmove` had been written - and possibly even do a better job.  (Of course, designing the data structure differently so that popping does not involve moving any elements would be much better!)

Comment: That's a bug in my code indeed. But it doesn't solve my segfault anyway.

Comment: @m-m -- Or one could maintain head and tail indexes into the array and avoid the moves completely. 

@outvader -- After you shift the `data` element over, shouldn't you null-out the last item in the array? Otherwise calling `queue_pop` on an empty queue would return garbage.

Comment: `queue_pop` is never called on an empty queue. I check that in case `q->size == 0`

Comment: When the queue is full, does `q->size == q->capacity`? If so the `free(q->data[q->size]);` line will access an element off end of the allocated array. (BTW, this seems like a really odd thing to do here.)

Comment: The queue doubles capacity when almost full (like a vector). [and still it's not what is causing my problem as this moment]

Answer (score 0):

Below seems to be a problem.

```
free(q->data[q->size]);
```

lets say two elements are in Queue `q->size = 2` hold by

`q->data[0]` and `q->data[1]`

so when queue_pop called. Above code will free `q->data[2]`. This may leads to seg-fault.